# Handling TPM2 tools command line changes

Tags: tpm, tpm-2.0

I'm working with TPM2 tools on CentOS 7 and CentOS 8, and it seems like the command line interface between the versions of tools has changed. So my 8 commands don't work on 7, and I have to write new ones. For example, while the hierarchy defaults to `owner` on 8's tools, it seems like it has to be explicitly specified on 7's tools.

Is there some simple way to deal with this that I don't know about? Like a flag to make the newer tools revert to the older tools command line interface?

Just thought I should ask before I go down the rabbit hole of figuring out when these changes happened (hopefully in a single version) and then writing dozens of shell wrapper functions to handle the differences.

Comment: Questions like these are much more easily answerable if you specify the details, e.g. which versions of tpm2-tools you are/were using and which tool you are talking about (with regard to the default hierarchy). If the question is vague, the answer will be, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some simple way to deal with this that I don't know about? Like a flag to make the newer tools revert to the older tools command line interface?

No.

> before I go down the rabbit hole of figuring out when these changes happened

There should be no need. The tpm2-tools follow Semantic Versioning. Therefore, breaking changes should only happen when the major version is increased (e.g. from `4.X` to `5.0`).

To find more information about the changes, see the tpm2-tools [Changelog](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/docs/CHANGELOG.md).

Also, see the man pages on GitHub (e.g. [for tpm2_getrandom)](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_getrandom.1.md). Here, you also get access to the history of the man pages.